# modifying hash in a ruby 1.8.7 module

Tags: ruby, module

I have a strange problem with a module I have implemented. I define a hash of key-value pairs and then replace the whitespace in the hash values with asterisks. When I try to load this module in IRB via:

```
load 'lib/protocols/myprotocol.rb'
```

I get the following syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: ./lib/protocols/myprotocol/errors.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'
./lib/protocols/myprotocol/errors.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting '}'
from (irb):23:in `load'
from (irb):23
```

Any ideas? It works when I comment the following line:

```
STATUS_CODES_MAP.each_value { |val| val.sub!(/\s/, 'Network error ' }
```

It seems the problem is related to modifying constant hashes inside a module, but I don't know the exact reason. Here is the module code:

```
module Protocols
  module MyProtocol
    STATUS_CODES_MAP = {
      'AuthError'    => 'Some error text',
      'AnotherError' => 'Another error text'
    }
    STATUS_CODES_MAP.each_value { |val| val.gsub!(/\s/, '*' }

    def error_from_response_status_code(status_code)
      error_from_response_code(STATUS_CODES_MAP, status_code, 'Unknown protocol error!')
    end

    def error_from_response_code(errors, code, unknown_error_msg)
      if errors.has_key?(code)
        return Base.error_from_string(errors[code])
      else
        RemoteError.new(unknown_error_msg)
       end
    end

    module_function :error_from_response_status_code
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
STATUS_CODES_MAP.each_value { |val| val.sub!(/\s/, 'Network error ' }
```

There is a syntax error here. ) is missing at the end.

And apart from that there should not be any problem in modifying the hash values.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are missing a `)`:

```
STATUS_CODES_MAP.each_value { |val| val.gsub!(/\s/, '*' }
```

vs

```
STATUS_CODES_MAP.each_value { |val| val.gsub!(/\s/, '*') }
```